# Wordpress limiting users to 13 pages?

Tags: wordpress

I designed a Wordpress site recently for a client and they can't post another page after 13 pages. I've heared of limits at like 3000 pages but why 13?

Comment: What do you mean "can't post"? They can't submit the post or it doesn't show up or what?

Comment: its limiting the number of pages.. its on yahoo! small business server. I can't add another page

Comment: instead of publish it says "Submit for Review" and when I click that it sends me to the 'posts' area and the page never shows up

Comment: Do you have a lot of content there? Many posts, pages etc.?

Answer (score 0):

My experience (and others in the Wordpress.org forums) with Yahoo Small Business and Wordpress is that their hosting is fundamentally crippled: no mod_rewrite and restrictions in their php config that you can't override with php.ini.